# Kivy strange displaying view on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I have a very strange result displaying in Kivy and running on a Raspberry PI.

Every `BoxLayout`is displayed twice and when I change the text of the label,
the words seem to overlap. I am very confused with why these results are occuring.

How can I fix this problem?

BoxLayout displays twice

[image]

The label's text overlapped when I change the text

[image]

And the upper and under text are changed at the same time

[image]

Here is my Python Code:

```
class ScheduleScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        pass

    def on_quit(self):
        global sm, event_idle
        sm.current = 'Normal'
        event_idle = Clock.schedule_once(BackMain, 60)


class ScheduleListItemButton(ListItemButton):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleListItemButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.height = "64dp"

class ScheduleMan(BoxLayout):
    week_day = StringProperty()
    week_day_up = Image()
    week_day_down = Image()
    start_hour = StringProperty()
    start_hour_up = Image()
    start_hour_down = Image()
    start_min = StringProperty()
    start_min_up = Image()
    start_min_down = Image()
    end_hour = StringProperty()
    end_hour_up = Image()
    end_hour_down = Image()
    end_min = StringProperty()
    end_min_up = Image()
    end_min_down = Image()
    week_day_num = 0
    start_hour_num = 0
    start_min_num = 0
    end_hour_num = 0
    end_min_num = 0
    schedule_list = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleMan, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.week_days = ["星期日", "星期一", "星期二", "星期三", "星期四", "星期五", "星期六"]
        self.init_value()
        self.schedules = []

    # Initial all properties
    def init_value(self):
        self.week_day = "星期日"
        self.start_hour = "00"
        self.start_min = "00"
        self.end_hour = "00"
        self.end_min = "00"
        self.week_day_num = 0
        self.start_hour_num = 0
        self.start_min_num = 0
        self.end_hour_num = 0
        self.end_min_num = 0

    def up_week_day(self):
        if self.week_day_num == 6:
            self.week_day_num = 0
        else:
            self.week_day_num += 1
        self.week_day = self.week_days[self.week_day_num]

    def down_week_day(self):
        if self.week_day_num == 0:
            self.week_day_num = 6
        else:
            self.week_day_num -= 1
        self.week_day = self.week_days[self.week_day_num]

    def up_start_hour(self):
        if self.start_hour_num >= 23:
            self.start_hour_num = 0
        else:
            self.start_hour_num += 1
        self.start_hour = "%02d" % self.start_hour_num

    def down_start_hour(self):
        if self.end_hour_num <= 0:
            self.end_hour_num = 23
        else:
            self.start_hour_num -= 1
        self.start_hour = "%02d" % self.start_hour_num

    def up_end_hour(self):
        if self.end_hour_num >= 23:
            self.end_hour_num = 0
        else:
            self.end_hour_num += 1
        self.end_hour = "%02d" % self.end_hour_num

    def down_end_hour(self):
        if self.end_hour_num <= 0:
            self.end_hour_num = 23
        else:
            self.end_hour_num -= 1
        self.end_hour = "%02d" % self.end_hour_num
    def up_start_min(self):
        if self.start_min_num >= 59:
            self.start_min_num = 0
        else:
            self.start_min_num += 1
        self.start_min = "%02d" % self.start_min_num

    def down_start_min(self):
        if self.end_min_num <= 0:
            self.end_min_num = 59
        else:
            self.start_min_num -= 1
        self.start_min = "%02d" % self.start_min_num

    def up_end_min(self):
        if self.end_min_num >= 59:
            self.end_min_num = 0
        else:
            self.end_min_num += 1
        self.end_min = "%02d" % self.end_min_num

    def down_end_min(self):
        if self.end_min_num <= 0:
            self.end_min_num = 59
        else:
            self.end_min_num -= 1
        self.end_min = "%02d" % self.end_min_num
```

and Here is my kv file:

```
<ScheduleScreen>:
    name: "Schedule"    
    ScheduleMan:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: buttonQuit
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {'right':1,'bottom':0.9}
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            text: "離開"
            on_press: root.on_quit()

<ScheduleListItemButton>:
    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
    font_size: 32
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "64dp"

<ScheduleMan>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    schedule_list: schedules_list_view
    padding: 20
    spacing: 20

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "64dp"
        spacing: 2

        Label:
            id: l_week_day
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: root.week_day
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: 2
            spacing: 15
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/up.png"
                on_press: root.up_week_day()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/down.png"
                on_press: root.down_week_day()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
        Label:
            id: l_start_hour
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: root.start_hour
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: 2
            spacing: 15
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/up.png"
                on_press: root.up_start_hour()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/down.png"
                on_press: root.down_start_hour()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
        Label:
            text: ":"
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
        Label:
            id: l_start_min
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: root.start_min
            spacing: 5
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: 2
            spacing: 15
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/up.png"
                on_press: root.up_start_min()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/down.png"
                on_press: root.down_start_min()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
        Label:
            text: " 至 "
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
        Label:
            id: l_end_hour
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: root.end_hour
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: 2
            spacing: 15
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/up.png"
                on_press: root.up_end_hour()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/down.png"
                on_press: root.down_end_hour()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
        Label:
            text: ":"
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
        Label:
            id: l_end_min
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: root.end_min
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: 2
            spacing: 15
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/up.png"
                on_press: root.up_end_min()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
            ImageButton:
                source: "../pic/down.png"
                on_press: root.down_end_min()
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 24
                height: 16
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "64dp"
        spacing: 15
        spacing: 5
        Button:
            text: "儲存修改"
            size_hint_x: 32
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.submit_schedule()
        Button:
            text: "剛除"
            size_hint_x: 32
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.delete_schedule()
        Button:
            text: "修改"
            size_hint_x: 32
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.update_schedule()
    ListView:
        id: schedules_list_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.ScheduleListItemButton)
```

Comment: On your computer you normally run?

Comment: No, still got the same strange result...

Comment: If the problem also plays on a normal PC then the problem has nothing to do with Raspberry but strictly with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I finally find the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workable version.

test5.py

```
import os
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import simplejson as json
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

strnow = lambda : str(datetime.now())
# init
base_path = os.getcwd()
pic_path = base_path + '/pic/'
conf_path = base_path + '/conf/'
kivy.resources.resource_add_path(base_path + '/font')


class ScheduleListButton(ListItemButton):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScheduleListButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_name = 'DroidSansFallback'
        self.height = 40
        pass


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class ScheduleDB(BoxLayout):

    # Connects the value in the TextInput widget to these
    # fields
    # first_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    # last_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    schedule_list = ObjectProperty()
    week_day_text = StringProperty()
    start_hour_text = StringProperty()
    start_min_text = StringProperty()
    end_hour_text = StringProperty()
    end_min_text = StringProperty()
    scheduleTexts = ListProperty()
    week_day_num = 0
    start_hour_num = 0
    start_min_num = 0
    end_hour_num = 0
    end_min_num = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleDB, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.week_days = ["星期一 ", "星期二 ", "星期三 ", "星期四 ", "星期五 ", "星期六", "星期日 " ]
        self.init_value()
        self.schedules = []
        with open(conf_path + "rule.json", "r") as fp:
            self.schedules = json.load(fp)
        print("Load from config : %s " % str(self.schedules))
        self.scheduleTexts = []
        for s in self.schedules:
            self.scheduleTexts.append("%s%s至%s" % (self.week_days[s["weekDay"]], s["beginTime"], s["endTime"]))
        #self.ids.schedule_list_view.adapter.data = self.scheduleTexts

    # Initial all properties
    def init_value(self):
        self.week_day_text = "星期一 "
        self.start_hour_text = "00"
        self.start_min_text = "00"
        self.end_hour_text = "00"
        self.end_min_text = "00"
        self.week_day_num = 0
        self.start_hour_num = 0
        self.start_min_num = 0
        self.end_hour_num = 0
        self.end_min_num = 0

    def up_week_day(self):
        # print("up_week_day, %d" % self.week_day_num)
        if self.week_day_num == 6:
            self.week_day_num = 0
        else:
            self.week_day_num += 1
        self.week_day_text = self.week_days[self.week_day_num]

    def down_week_day(self):
        # print("down_week_day, %d" % self.week_day_num)
        if self.week_day_num == 0:
            self.week_day_num = 6
        else:
            self.week_day_num -= 1
        self.week_day_text = self.week_days[self.week_day_num]

    def up_start_hour(self):
        # print("up_start_hour, %d" % self.start_hour_num)
        if self.start_hour_num >= 23:
            self.start_hour_num = 0
        else:
            self.start_hour_num += 1
        self.start_hour_text = "%02d" % self.start_hour_num

    def down_start_hour(self):
        # print("down_start_hour, %d" % self.start_hour_num)
        if self.start_hour_num <= 0:
            self.start_hour_num = 23
        else:
            self.start_hour_num -= 1
        self.start_hour_text = "%02d" % self.start_hour_num

    def up_start_min(self):
        # print("up_start_min, %d" % self.start_min_num)
        if self.start_min_num >= 59:
            self.start_min_num = 0
        else:
            self.start_min_num += 1
        self.start_min_text = "%02d" % self.start_min_num

    def down_start_min(self):
        # print("down_start_min, %d" % self.start_min_num)
        if self.start_min_num <= 0:
            self.start_min_num = 59
        else:
            self.start_min_num -= 1
        self.start_min_text = "%02d" % self.start_min_num

    def up_end_hour(self):
        # print("up_end_hour, %d" % self.end_hour_num)
        if self.end_hour_num >= 23:
            self.end_hour_num = 0
        else:
            self.end_hour_num += 1
        self.end_hour_text = "%02d" % self.end_hour_num

    def down_end_hour(self):
        # print("down_end_hour, %d" % self.end_hour_num)
        if self.end_hour_num <= 0:
            self.end_hour_num = 23
        else:
            self.end_hour_num -= 1
        self.end_hour_text = "%02d" % self.end_hour_num

    def up_end_min(self):
        # print("up_end_min, %d" % self.end_min_num)
        if self.end_min_num >= 59:
            self.end_min_num = 0
        else:
            self.end_min_num += 1
        self.end_min_text = "%02d" % self.end_min_num

    def down_end_min(self):
        # print("down_end_min, %d" % self.end_min_num)
        if self.end_min_num <= 0:
            self.end_min_num = 59
        else:
            self.end_min_num -= 1
        self.end_min_text = "%02d" % self.end_min_num

class ScheduleScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        pass


class test5App(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScheduleScreen()
        #return ScheduleDB()


dbApp = test5App()
dbApp.run()
```

test5.kv

```
# Reference test5.py
#: import main test5
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

ScheduleDB:

<ScheduleDB>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    #first_name_text_input: first_name
    #last_name_text_input: last_name
    schedule_list: schedule_list_view
    padding: 2
    spacing: 2

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "64dp"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 2
            spacing: 2
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, .5
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                ImageButton:
                    id: UpWeekDay
                    source: "pic/up.png"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 30
                    on_press: root.up_week_day()
                ImageButton:
                    id: DownWeekDay
                    source: "pic/down.png"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 30
                    on_press: root.down_week_day()
            Label:
                id: week_day
                font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                font_size: 32
                text: root.week_day_text
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 2
            spacing: 2
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_x: 1.8
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 1, 1, .5
                Label:
                    id: start_hour
                    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                    font_size: 32
                    text: root.start_hour_text
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    ImageButton:
                        id: UpStartHour
                        source: "pic/up.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.up_start_hour()
                    ImageButton:
                        id: DownStartHour
                        source: "pic/down.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.down_start_hour()
                Label:
                    id: l1
                    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                    font_size: 32
                    text: ":"
                Label:
                    id: start_min
                    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                    font_size: 32
                    text: root.start_min_text
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    ImageButton:
                        id: UpStartMin
                        source: "pic/up.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.up_start_min()
                    ImageButton:
                        id: DownStartMin
                        source: "pic/down.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.down_start_min()
            Label:
                id: till
                font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                font_size: 32
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                text: "至"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_x: 1.8
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 1, 1, .5
                Label:
                    id: end_hour
                    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                    font_size: 32
                    text: root.end_hour_text
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    ImageButton:
                        id: UpEndHour
                        source: "pic/up.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.up_end_hour()
                    ImageButton:
                        id: DownEndHour
                        source: "pic/down.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.down_end_hour()
                Label:
                    id: l2
                    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                    font_size: 32
                    text: ":"
                Label:
                    id: end_min
                    font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
                    font_size: 32
                    text: root.end_min_text
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    ImageButton:
                        id: UpEndtMin
                        source: "pic/up.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.up_end_min()
                    ImageButton:
                        id: DownEndMin
                        source: "pic/down.png"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 30
                        on_press: root.down_end_min()

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "48dp"
        Button:
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: "新增"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.submit_schedule()
        Button:
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: "刪除"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.delete_schedule()
        Button:
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            font_size: 32
            text: "更改"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.replace_schedule()

    # Define starting data and point to the ListItemButton
    # in the Python code
    ListView:
        id: schedule_list_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=root.scheduleTexts, cls=main.ScheduleListButton)

<ScheduleScreen>:
    name: "Schedule"
    ScheduleDB:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: buttonQuit
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {'right':1,'top':0.95}
            font_name: 'DroidSansFallback'
            text: "離開"
```